# How to add Alt and Title for SEO to a Responsive design using Figure tag

Tags: html, css, image, seo

How can I build a responsive Mobile First page with images optimized for SEO with Alt and Title?

At the moment I change the image source in the CSS file like this:

```
section.value-offer > div.container > figure {
    background: url('../Images/Shop/img.childrens.480x320.jpg') top center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-bottom: 66.66666666%;
    height: 0;
}
```

And in the HTML I use only:

```
<figure></figure>
```

Then in the CSS responsive part for the next page size I do:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
    background: url('../Images/Shop/img.childrens.768x511.jpg') top center no-repeat;
}
```

But I can't do:

```
<figure alt="Image of Childrens" title="Image of Childrens"></figure>
```

And I can't put the IMG tag with the SRC because I can't change it using CSS only.

Comment: Background images aren't subject to SEO! They're **styling**. That's like trying to apply SEO to a border-color.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I only want to use CSS to manage the image src for the responsive design.

Comment: Then you have a problem. The `figure` element is **intended** to hold an image. If it's empty...it's not being used properly. You might want to look into `srcset`.

Comment: @Paulie_D Hi, thanks! So what is your suggestion to change the image src for responsive design?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Comment: @Paulie_D https://caniuse.com/#search=srcset it's not supported in IE :S

Comment: Then you need to re-think your requirements. This has **accessibility** issues too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like these images to ever rank in any modern search engine image search (and that is the purpose of your question I guess) then you should not use them as css background images as this would not get indexed by them. Going for semantic html (`<figure>`) is a right choice but depending on the image and content structure you can also use plain old `<img>` tag.  Here is a good starting point if you need to find out more about [responsive images](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_responsive.asp).

Also I would recommend using fore mentioned scrset, despite IE's lack of adoption of this attribute. There is a easy work around, IE will ignore `scrset` attribute but still use the `src` so you can source your default IE image from there:

```
<img src="default.jpg" srcset="medium.jpg 1000w, large.jpg 2000w" alt="your_alt">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! The issue with this solution is that you only have 1 image for all the devices, from FullHD (1920px) to Mobile (360px) and I am trying to avoid a mobile user to download a FullHD image in his phone serving him only with the image size he needs for his device.

Comment: Yes that is where srcset comes into play. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Can you share an example including the IE workaround?

Answer (score 2):

If you have SEO / cross browser (including IE) constraints, I would suggest this

**Have a mobile first approach with such HTML**

```
<figure alt="Image of Childrens" title="Image of Childrens">
<img alt="Image of Childrens" title="Image of Childrens" src="../Images/Shop/img.childrens.480x320.jpg" />
</figure>
```

It means that by default, client (mobile here) will fetch the smaller image dedicated to mobile

**Then, for larger screen (desktop or even tablet), you will have such applied CSS**

```
    @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width: 1023) {
        section.value-offer > div.container > figure{
background: url('../Images/Shop/img.childrens.768x511.jpg') top center no-repeat;
    }
}
   @media only screen and (min-width : 1024px) and (max-width: 1280) {
        section.value-offer > div.container > figure{
background: url('../Images/Shop/img.childrens.1024x720.jpg') top center no-repeat;
    }
}
```

If your media queries are well defined, it means that yes: desktop will download the smaller image in all cases + a much larger one.
But at least, you limit the size of downloaded assets for mobile, also assuming that desktop are on a more solid connexion.